# How to obtain UTF-8 reader in PythonInterpreter (jython)?

Tags: java, python, utf-8, jboss, jython

I am using embedded Jython (version 2.5.3) in my web application and I try to do this in my Java code:

```
PythonInterpreter pythonInterpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
pythonInterpreter.exec("import codecs");
pythonInterpreter.exec("codecs.getreader('utf8')");
```

But I get this error:

```
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "__pyclasspath__/codecs$py.class", line 920, in getreader
LookupError: no codec search functions registered: can't find encoding 'utf8'
```

How can the reader with 'utf8' encoding be obtained properly?

According to the python documentation, there should be 'utf8' encoding available in codecs module: https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings (lower / upper case and hyphen / underscore are all allowed).

I use Windows 7, java 1.7.0_71. OS should not matter I guess - this is the web application run on jboss (version 7.2). The problem occurs on both jython-standalone-2.5.3.jar and regular jython-2.5.3.jar.

Comment: That document only shows "utf_8", "U8" "UTF" and "utf8" as valid aliases. True, it also says "a hyphen instead of an underscore are also valid aliases; therefore, e.g. 'utf-8' is a valid alias for the 'utf_8' codec." But neither "UTF_8" nor "UTF-8" (i.e. all-caps versions) are listed. Have you tried the lower-case version or one of the actually listed aliases?

Comment: I have tried different options ('UTF-8', 'utf8', 'utf_8'), but the result is the same. I've edited the question and replaced 'UTF-8' for 'utf8' though, to make it clearer.

Comment: Does your code work in an interactive Jython session?  Which OS?  Which version of Java?  This code works fine for my on Jython2.5.3 running on both Ubuntu 11.04 and Windows 7 on Java8u31.

Comment: I've added OS, java and jboss versions to the question. Does my code work in an interactive Jython session? I don't know exactly what do you mean, so probably not... It's packed into .war and deployed on jboss eventually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to find a solution to this problem - this was a configuration error. It works now, after changing the code to:

```
import java.util.Properties;
import org.python.util.PythonInterpreter;

(...)

Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty("python.path", pythonPath);
PythonInterpreter.initialize(System.getProperties(), properties, new String[] { "" });
PythonInterpreter pythonInterpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
pythonInterpreter.exec("import codecs");
pythonInterpreter.exec("codecs.getreader('utf8')");
```

where `pythonPath` is the path to the “Lib” directory in the jython-2.5.3.jar, in the deployed WAR.

I ended up wrapping it all up in some PostConstruct Spring method, which is invoked when starting Spring context.